# Modify color java object

Tags: java, colors

In **Java** I have declared this color object:

```
Color f_color = new Color(0,0,0);
```

Later in the code I would like to update that color variable setting, for instance, the red channel to 2. I try to do so in the following way:

```
f_color.r = 2;
```

Obviously I get an error. Is it possible to do what I am trying to ? or the only way is to create a new color object? Thank you.

Comment: use 3 variables to hold r g b value and then change those values

Comment: Color class doesn't have setters, you can call the brighter() or darker() methods though. Refer to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html).

Comment: @getlost I'm pretty sure that won't work.

Comment: @Compass that's really funny .@nem knows that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only way would be to create a new [**`Color`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) object, at least to my knowledge.

There are no setter() methods in the `Color` class.

However, you can store your colors in variables and then create a new color with updated values:

```
int r = 0;
int g = 0;
int b = 0;

Color f_color = new Color(r,g,b);

// ...

r = 2;                           // update red channel 
f_color = new Color(r,g,b);      // assign new color
```

Answer (score 2):

`Color` is immutable.  You'll have to create a new one:

```
Color newColor = new Color(oldColor.getRed()+2, oldColor.getGreen(), oldColor.getBlue());
```